# Deserialize objects to plain string

Tags: java, gson

Is It possible to deserialize a json to POJO's while some of the children objects remain a json string? Example:

```
{
  a_num: 5,
  an_object : { ... },
  a_string: "a cool string"
}
```

to a POJO with:

```
int a_num;
//instead of: ObjectType an_object;
String an_object;
String a_string;
```

Comment: Not by default. Write a custom `TypeAdapter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answer of Jigar I could deduce a simpler solution for this case of problem.

A very easy way to save the time of mapping every variable is to write a deserializer for the string class and then declare the wanted variable as a string.

```
public class StringDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        return jsonElement.toString();
    }
}
```

While using following POJO:

```
int a_num;
String an_object;
String a_string;
```

And finally registering the TypeAdapter:

```
private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
  .registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new StringDeserializer()).create();
```

With this deserializer it is possible to deserialize any field you want as a string. Just type it to a string in the POJO.

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom deserializer for [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) api you can implement `JsonDeserializer`

**for example:**

```
public class MyClass implements JsonDeserializer<MyClass>{

//fields and constructor

@Override
public MyClass deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    JsonObject jobject = (JsonObject) json;

    return new MyClass(
            jobject.get("a_num").getAsInt(), 
            jobject.get("an_object").getAsString(),
            jobject.get("a_string").getAsString() 
    );
}
}
```

Comment: nice answer! Could deduce a slightly better solution from it